# OLS - Weekly Rate of Change Trend and Interpretation

Tags: regression, interpretation, trend

I have the following data-set to determine the net difference on a weekly basis between the units sold column.

```
timeKey  units  netDifference   netChange   outlier
  0       59          6             0          0
  1       64          5            -1          0
  2       66          2            -3          0
  3       76         10             8          0
  4       98         22            12          0
  5       112        14            -8          0
```

Data Defintions:

```
units         = total number of units sold for the week
netDifference = units[timeKey] - units[timeKey - 1]
netChange     = netDifference[timeKey] - units[netDifference - 1]
outlier       = IQR assessment to determine if units sold number is an outlier
```

The average netDifference is 9.8, which says on average you are selling 9.8 more units per week.

Now I want to determine the trend of the weekly rate of change, so whether the actual number of units sold is increasing or decreasing each week.

If I perform a simple ols fit to the netDiffernce column, it comes out like this, where it is saying that netDifference is increasing each week, seen by the slope of the red trend line:

[image]

But then I thought that actually the rate of change should be determined by the weekly change between netDifference. So when I build the ols on the netChange column, the slope in the trend line is actually the saying that the rate of change each week is relatively stable as seen below:

[image]

So based on the what is stated above, using average netDifference and ols fitted to netChange, can someone please confirm whether the following interpretation is correct:

Over the previous 6 weeks, you have sold 9.8 more units each week on average, with the rate at which you are increasing the number of units you are selling each week remaining relatively stable.

Comment: In every week you sold more than 9.8 units, so how could that be the average units sold per week?

Comment: This is the same mistake you were making before.

Comment: I’d encourage you to make this a time series. Then you would be determining whether or not the trend is additive (increasing by 9.8 units) or multiplicative (increasing by 8% per week). With either approach you need more data— I would put a huge band of uncertainty around your OLS trend line.